# Efficient time series sliding window function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, rolling-computation

I am trying to create a sliding window for a time series. So far I have a function that I managed to get working that lets you take a given series, set a window size in seconds and then create a rolling sample. My issue is that it is taking very long to run and seems like an inefficient approach.

```
# ========== create dataset  =========================== #

import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


timestamp_list = ["2022-02-07 11:38:08.625",
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:09.676", 
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:10.084", 
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:10.10000",  
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:11.2320"]

bid_price_list = [1.14338, 
                  1.14341, 
                  1.14340, 
                  1.1434334, 
                  1.1534334]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(zip(timestamp_list, bid_price_list))
df.columns = ['timestamp','value']

# make date time object
df.timestamp = [datetime.strptime(time_i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for time_i in df.timestamp]
```

```
df.head(3)
timestamp   value   timestamp_to_sec
0   2022-02-07 11:38:08.625 1.14338 2022-02-07 11:38:08
1   2022-02-07 11:38:09.676 1.14341 2022-02-07 11:38:09
2   2022-02-07 11:38:10.084 1.14340 2022-02-07 11:38:10
```

```
# ========== create rolling time-series function  ====== #


# get the floor of time (second value)
df["timestamp_to_sec"]  = df["timestamp"].dt.floor('s')

# set rollling window length in seconds
window_dt = pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)

# containers for rolling sample statistics
n_list = []
mean_list = []
std_list =[]

# add dt (window) seconds to the original time which was floored to the second
df["timestamp_to_sec_dt"] = df["timestamp_to_sec"]  + window_dt

# get unique end times
time_unique_endlist = np.unique(df.timestamp_to_sec_dt)

# remove end times that are greater than the last actual time, i.e. max(df["timestamp_to_sec"])
time_unique_endlist = time_unique_endlist[time_unique_endlist <= max(df["timestamp_to_sec"])]

# loop running the sliding window (time_i is the end time of each window)
for time_i in time_unique_endlist:
    
    # start time of each rolling window
    start_time = time_i - window_dt
    
    # sample for each time period of sliding window
    rolling_sample = df[(df.timestamp >= start_time) & (df.timestamp <= time_i)]

    
    # calculate the sample statistics
    n_list.append(len(rolling_sample)) # store n observation count
    mean_list.append(rolling_sample.mean()) # store rolling sample mean
    std_list.append(rolling_sample.std()) # store rolling sample standard deviation
    
    # plot histogram for each sample of the rolling sample
    #plt.hist(rolling_sample.value, bins=10)
```

```
# tested and n_list brought back the correct values
>>> n_list
[2,3]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, a way I could improve my interpretation or an open-source package that allows me to run a rolling window like this? I know that there is the `.rolling()` in pandas but that rolls on the values. I want something that I can use on unevenly-spaced data, using the time to define the fixed rolling window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is the best performance, hope it helps anyone else.

```
# set rollling window length in seconds
window_dt = pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)

# add dt seconds to the original timestep
df["timestamp_to_sec_dt"] = df["timestamp_to_sec"]  + window_dt

# unique end time
time_unique_endlist = np.unique(df.timestamp_to_sec_dt)

# remove end values that are greater than the last actual value, i.e. max(df["timestamp_to_sec"])
time_unique_endlist = time_unique_endlist[time_unique_endlist <= max(df["timestamp_to_sec"])]

# containers for rolling sample statistics
mydic = {}
counter = 0

# loop running the rolling window
for time_i in time_unique_endlist:
    
    start_time = time_i - window_dt
    
    # sample for each time period of sliding window
    rolling_sample = df[(df.timestamp >= start_time) & (df.timestamp <= time_i)]

    # calculate the sample statistics
    mydic[counter] = {
                        "sample_size":len(rolling_sample),
                        "sample_mean":rolling_sample["value"].mean(),
                        "sample_std":rolling_sample["value"].std()
                        }
    counter = counter + 1

# results in a DataFrame
results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic).T
```

Comment: This works nicely, but what if you are reading data from a very large file, or automatically from a continuous log -- how do you avoid having an infinitely large dataframe? Also, pandas dataframes aren't great for appending incoming entries to because you copy the whole df in the process... any ideas how to get around this to use pandas for an "infinite" time series with a rolling window?